# Custom JComponent not showing in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jcomponent

I'm having a problem placing a custom JComponent on a JPanel.
The JPanel is located in the main JFrame with absolute Positioning. All fine until now.

My custom JComponent draws a simple rectangle and is also added to the JPanel by absolute positioning.

The problem is that it isn't shown on the Panel. Letting the JPanel draw the rectangle works but this is not what I want to do.

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {

    public MyComponent ()
    {
        this.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50); 
    }


    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() 
    {
        Return new Dimension(50, 50);
    }


    @Override
    public Point getLocation(Point arg0)
    {   
        return new Point(50, 50);
    }

}
```

Comment: _The JPanel is located in the main JFrame with absolute Positioning. All fine until now._ Let me put some serious doubt on that: asbolute positioning is always a nightmare for any Swing developer. Overriding `getLocation` won't change the location of your component. Finally, it's impossible to diagnose your issue with the code you provided. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: `g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);` and you overrode getPreferredSize() with `new Dimension(50, 50);`, so basically the tope left corner of the rectangle you draw is the bottom righ-corner of your component-->unlikely to ever show up.

Comment: Thanks very much! It was the rect that is drawn outside the component. Very dumb of me..

Comment: Do **not** override `getLocation`! This will return results that are inconsistent will all other methods of `Component`. For example, `getBounds` will return bounds whose upper left corner are *different* from what `getLocation` returns. This may cause arbitrarly ugly errors!